# Symfony2 : Include entity model from another bundle cause Doctrine error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am asking here because i could not found on Google how to solve this and maybe someone with more experience already know the solution.

And as I see on Google, there are very much person with this same problem (alot of web pages indexed containing this SF2 error)

So I tried to add in my controller "use" an entity from another bundle, but I get that PHP error :

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Persistent' not found in ~/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Propel1/Tests/Fixtures/Item.php on line 17
```

Am I doing something wrong when im including my entity from another bundle with "use" ?

```
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice;
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Quote;
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Item;

class MembershipController extends BaseController          {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

When I use those entity inside that same bundle of entities, this problem does not occurs .. Very weird.

Thank you very much and have a great day !

Comment: If those are `Doctrine` entities then the real question is why the error mentions `Propel` :-/

Comment: Also, can you copy/paste your `doctrine` block from `config.yml`?

Comment: Yeah sure its very weird that it says Propel when in reality I only use Doctrine2 .. I don't even known that Symfony2 is built in with Propel.

Comment: # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, I made a mistake with the multiple "use", but I think anyway that this solution may help some peoples.

```
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice;
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Quote;
use FOOBAR\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Item;
```

In those, I was supposed to replace "InvoiceBundle" with "PaymentBundle" (because InvoiceBundle doesn't even exists ..)

So what caused this particular error ? Later in my source code I declare this :

```
$item = new Item;
```

So the error about **Propel1/Tests/Fixtures/Item.php** I think this was because Symfony2 tried to call the Item file in that class because he couldn't find the right "Item" class.